# Facebook for Business Messenger with Salesforce Live Message?

Tags: liveagent, facebook

I see references to the standard Facebook messenger but, nothing with Facebook for Business. I know nothing about Facebook for Business, so is it the same integration configuration? The company I am working with is happily on the Facebook for Business platform. We would like to be able to integrate Facebook for Business messenger with Salesforce Live Message as part of a Community rollout. Is it possible? How can it be done?

Answer (score 2):

Saleforce Live Message supports facebook messenger, and is available to your support reps who have a service cloud license.  Facebook messenger is, in essence (as far as integrations go), the same for businesses as it is for individuals, so the rollout will be the same on that side.  When users message with your company's facebook account, your service reps will be able to respond directly to them within the live message console.

As far as communities go, that will be separate from live message.  Live message is for when folks are communicating with your company via text or messenger outside of salesforce.  When somebody reaches out to your company on facebook messenger, the service rep will see information about them, and perhaps the customer may be an existing community user, but the customer doesn't need to be a community user to interact with your business via Live Message.

The videos here about live message and live agent might help you understand better how it all works.

https://www.salesforce.com/form/conf/demo-service.jsp

I hope this is helpful.

Comment: It is helpful to know that the integrations would be the same. Do you happen to know where there is an example or documentation of using FB messenger with Live Message? All the references I have found so far are at the marketing level only, i.e., "It can" versus "This is how". Thanks in advance!

Comment: finding this out would be extremely useful, anything?